# How to hide undefined variable in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, undefined

*Just an FYI before you continue reading...I'm not the type to run to stackoverflow every time I can't figure out a solution to my problem but this one has really got my head spinning.*

How do I hide an undefined variable inside of an array:

```
var state_zip = address.split(',')[2];
```

I want the variable state_zip to output as blank "" instead of "undefined" when outputting data.

These didn't seem to work for me either.

```
ar more2 = address.split(',')[4];if (more2.split(',')[4]=="undefined"){more2=""} 
ar more2 = address.split(',')[4];if (more2.split(' ')=="undefined"){more2=""}
```

Anyone who can help me understand this would be greatly appreciated. I'm more of a backend developer so this is a little bit out of my normal environment.

Comment: Try trimming it? Also, check where its displaying the data that it hasnt got something to check if its empty to say "undefined" instead

Answer (score 3):

Try using [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof):

```
if ('undefined' === typeof state_zip)
  state_zip = '';
```

Comment: True, but better avoid having `undefined` there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
> var address = 'asd';
> var state_zip = address.split(',')[2];
> console.log(state_zip);
undefined
> var state_zip = address.split(',')[2] || '';
> console.log(state_zip);

>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use quotes around `undefined`. You should be checking for `undefined` in the following way -

```
var more2 = address.split(',')[4];if (more2.split(',')[4]==undefined){more2=""} 
var more2 = address.split(',')[4];if (more2.split(' ')==undefined){more2=""}
```

When you use quotes around `undefined`, you are basically checking whether or not that variable contains the string `"undefined"`.

An [example](http://jsfiddle.net/2esnt/) on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Isn't undefined a javascript keyword?  You should be able to do

```
if(more2.split(',')[4] == undefined) more2 = "";
```

No need for quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Check the array length:

```
var arrAddress = address.split(',');
var more2 = (arrAddress.length >= 5) ? arrAddress[4] : "";
```

When you try to read JS array beyond its bounds, you get undefined - so just make sure you're within the bounds otherwise assign empty string.

You can make it more generic by having such function once:

```
function GetItem(array, index) {
   return (index >= 0 && index < array.length) ? array[index] : "";
}
```

Then call it like:

```
var more2 = GetItem(arrAddress, 4);
var more3 = GetItem(arrAddress, 5);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using jquery you can do something like:

var more2 = address.split(',');

$.each( more2, function(i, l){

```
  more2[i] = (more2[i] == undefined) ? '' : more2[i];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pad the string if it's too short;

```
var template = ",,,," //a comma per expected entry
var address  = "123 street,town"

address = (address + template.substr(address.split(',').length)).split(",");

>>address = [123 street,town,,]

var state_zip = address[2];

>>state_zip = ""
```